# Using regex to capture string inside double quotation marks without quotation

Tags: regex

There is a function script, `var f = new Process("name01", "code01", "version01");` 
I want to use a regular expression to filter to get the name01 property. But this filter: ***"([^"]+)"*** works for the all properties.

```
"name01"
"code01"
"version01"
```

How can I get the name property without double quotaions, here is ***`name01`***, it is the first parameter in the function. It only appears after the Process keyword.

***Edit1:*** In my first quesiton, the both patterns `(?<=Process\(")[^\r\n"]*` and `\bProcess\("([^"]+)"[^()]*\)` work for the case. Thanks.

***Edit2:*** It happens that another requirment to retrieve the all 3 arguments of the process function from the text script below:

`var f = pmb.Process("name01", "code01", "version01")
            .Task("name01", "code01");`

I need to get the process function argument:

```
name01
code01
version01
```

And dont need the task function argument. Firstly(Thanks the Fouth Bird),

```
\bProcess\([^()]*\)
```

This only matched `Process("name01", "code01", "version01")`, should I use the second pattern to filter it to get the 3 arguments? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe,

```
(?<=\(")[^\r\n"]*
```

or

```
(?<=Process\(")[^\r\n"]*
```

might be OK to look into, I guess, if lookbehind is supported.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/UPmyU6/1/)

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/VsvCmR/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VsvCmR/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/VsvCmR/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a positive lookbehind as the only thing missing from your pattern to match the first value between double quotes is prepending an opening parenthesis:

```
\("([^"]+)"
^^
```

- `\("` Match `(` and `"`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^"]+` Match 1+ times any char except `"`
- `)"` Close group and match "

The value is in the first capturing group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xvKwGf/1)

---

If you also want to make sure that there is a closing parenthesis and that is starts with Process:

```
\bProcess\("([^"]+)"[^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YKYGD9/1)